# Using OpenStreetMap for routing in GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I am new in OSM but now I need create application which will use GIS (Geoserver) and will be provide service to get road from point A to point B.

I found some informations about this but I still have any questions. My is download open street maps and extract to database (PostgreSQL), and for routing use plugin pgRouting. Next connect db to map server and provide api for clients.

Is that correct way?

How osm format could I use for postgre? (osm.pbf? shp.zip?, or something else?)

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/ check out this link for downloading bulk data in various formats from OSM. I dont know much about pgrouting but this will help you with data finding

Comment: cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062819/use-osm-for-routing-in-geoserver-the-best-practise

Answer (score 1):

Using osm2pgrouting, you can load your OSM data into PostGIS http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html

Then follow the pgRouting tutorial http://pgrouting.org/documentation.html to get a handle on what pgRouting is doine.

From there, once you can get your pgRouting setup to work strictly within PostGIS, then Geoserver will merely serve as a conduit between your PostGIS database and the web through paramaterized SQL queries exposed by GUI's on your website.

Check this presentation for some information:

http://www.slideshare.net/kastl/pg-routing-presentation-foss4g-europe

I wish Daniel Kastl's video from FOSS4G in Portland was still online, but I think that presentation above is close...

Comment: Let's add the pgRouting workshop probably does exactly what you have in mind. Here the correct URL: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is a workshop on the Boundless website that shows how to build an end-to-end routing application based on OpenStreetMap data using the following open-source components:

- PostgreSQL/PostGIS
- pgRouting
- GeoServer
- OpenLayers

It was written a few years ago so some of the information will be a little outdated, particularly when it comes to the web application. You do not need to download PostgreSQL, PostGIS, pgRouting or GeoServer from Boundless; the community editions will work perfectly well. You can also avoid the Boundless SDK but it will take a little more work. The good news is that the JavaScript application is downloadable from the workshop, so you only need to author the HTML file.

Link: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/

If you do try it, please post any issues that you run into since they can probably be addressed without too much trouble.